# Get previous work day

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to get previous work day:

```
public DateTime GetPreviousWorkDay(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime prevDay = date.AddDays(-1);
    bool isHoliday = IsHoliday(prevDay);
    while (isHoliday || prevDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || prevDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        prevDay = prevDay.AddDays(-1);
        isHoliday = IsHoliday(prevDay);
    }
    return prevDay;
}
```

Is this method safe? Can it be an infinite cycle? Is there an simpler way?

Comment: Looks fine to me. How about you just test it and find out? What prompted this question? What do you mean by "is this method safe"?

Comment: Have you checked it with DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: As much as anything else, the "safety" of this method will depend on the definition of `IsHoliday`...

Comment: You can put IsHoliday(prevDay) in the while() and save 2 lines of code. That's look fine for me.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I hope not. I wouldn't consider DateTime.MinValue valid input to this function. Although a precise boundary between "valid" and "invalid" is hard to make, wherever it is, DateTime.MinValue will probably be on the far wrong end of that boundary.

Comment: @tnw Can it be infinite cycle? And maybe easier way exists

Comment: @Olena I don't see how it can. It will loop at most 4 or 5 times if `prevDay` is a Friday or something. You'll eventually hit a Saturday or Sunday (or a holiday) as you call `AddDays(-1)` in the loop, inevitably breaking you out of the loop

Comment: @tnw That makes some assumptions about how `IsHoliday` is implemented.  For all we know it's `return true;` ;).  It's *probably* not going to loop forever though, at least one would hope.

Comment: @Servy The only possibility would be if `IsHoliday` never returns. As long as it returns, the loop *will* hit a weekend and break out of the loop.

Comment: @tnw It loops *while* it's a weekend or a holiday, not while it's *not* a weekend or a holiday.  If all weekdays are holidays then it loops forever.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To make logic more clear, I'd extracted `IsWeekend` method and removed unnecessary temp variables. Simple *do..while* loop will do the job:

```
public DateTime PreviousWorkDay(DateTime date)
{
    do 
    {        
        date = date.AddDays(-1);        
    } 
    while(IsHoliday(date) || IsWeekend(date));

    return date;
}

private bool IsWeekend(DateTime date)
{
    return date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
           date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
}
```

Comment: you can make static methods. It'll be better.

Comment: @tnw for exemple : private static bool IsWeekend(DateTime date){...}

Comment: @Xaruth That doesn't answer the question at all. *How* would static methods be better in this case?

Comment: @tnw not only in this case, in general case. CA1822 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245046.aspx

Comment: @Xaruth in general case static members will make your code tightly coupled, and it's really headache to unit-test code which uses static dependencies. So, I always think twice before making something static